# How to solve a variation of Merton's optimal portfolio problem?

Tags: macroeconomics, finance, dynamic-programming, stochastic-calculus

Does anyone know how to solve the following problem?

I have tried to solve this  but I'm lost since I have never dealt with a Stochastic Dynamic Programming problem with many variables.

$max_{c_{t},\phi_{t}}\ E_{0}[\sum_{{t=0}}^{\infty}\beta^t\ln(C_{t})]$

$s.t. \ W_{t+1}=(W_t-C_t)[\phi_tR_{t+1}+(1-\phi_t)R_f]$ with $W_{0}$ given

$R_{f}$ represents the gross return of a riskless asset and $R_{f}=(1+r)$ and $R_{t}$ is the return of a risky asset. $R_{t+1}$ is an $i.i.d.$ random variable with unkown cumulative distribution $F$.

I am supposed to solve the exersice using dynamic programming (bellman equation) by finding the optimal policy functions.  I need to prove that the optimal share of the risky asset, $\phi_t$, is constant.

I am also given a guess for the value function which is $V(W)=F+Gln(W)$.

Comment: Have you given it an attempt?

Comment: Sure, I found $C=W/(\beta G+1)$ but I'm stuck when it comes to finding $\phi$. I'm not sure how to operate with with the expectation.

Comment: Shouldn't you get an Euler equation for $c_t$?

Comment: I think that If you get the FOC from the value function using the guess and replace $W_{t+1}$ with the rhs of the dynamic contraint you can avoid the Euler equation and get the policy for C, as a function of the unkown coefficient F and the state variable W.

Comment: I meant the coefficient G from the guess...

Comment: Oh ya duh. Okay I just replicated your answer for C. Attempting the other.

Comment: I get something like this for the second part where I'm stuck: $0=\frac{\partial V(W)}{\partial \phi}=\beta G E_{t}[\frac{R_{+1}-R_{f}}{\phi R_{+1}-\phi R_{f}+R_{f}}]$.

Comment: I got that too. That's a concave function in $R_{t+1}$ but  I see your point on not sure where to go next.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe if I assume that the distribution of the random variable is normal, I can get this through the moment generating function $e^{E[ln(R_{+1}-R_{f})-ln(\phi R_{+1}-\phi R_{f}+R_{f})]+\frac{1}{2}V[ln(R_{+1}-R_{f})-ln(\phi R_{+1}-\phi R_{f}+R_{f})]}$ but I don't see if it gets me anywhere, can't still isolate the $\phi$.

Comment: Here's a thought: the only variables in the derivative for $\phi$ are constants and $R_{t+1}$ which you are taking an expectation of, so that will also be a constant. C and W are not present.

Comment: I think I'm not following, isn't $\phi$ is still a variable?

Comment: If we could solve for $\phi$ it would be a function of only constants.